# Create an array from input field values with Flex 4.5

Tags: arrays, flex4.5, textinput

I have not been able to find any documentation and searches return useless docs not involving what I want to do.

I want to take the text entered by the user, and when they click `Add Record` it adds the text to the array. The list box at the bottom displays each item in the array in the order it was entered.

I am just a beginner with a basic understanding of how the code is written, but I have no idea which things to use in order to take the text, make it into a string, add it to the array, and display the array in the list.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick here is to just use the buttons click event to add an item to the ArrayCollection you use to provide the data to your list. Here's the sample I just came up with which does what I think you are asking:

```
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    title="HomeView">

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        [Bindable]
        private var _records:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

        protected function addRecord(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if(textInput.text != "") {
                _records.addItem(textInput.text);
            }
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:TextInput id="textInput" left="10" right="10" top="5" prompt="Enter Text" />
<s:Button top="64" label="Add Record" horizontalCenter="0" click="addRecord(event)" />
<s:List left="10" right="10" top="132" bottom="5" dataProvider="{_records}" />
</s:View>
```